# Random behaviour when pipping find output to xargs and then to sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed, xargs

I'm using the gnu version of these tools. I'm trying to unzip an archive and transform a file.

The file is "myfile.txt" and it appears in multiple folders in the archive- so I thought passing the full path to xarg would transform all files:

```
mkdir temp
unzip mypackage.zip -d temp

find temp -iname "myfile.txt" | xargs -I FILE sh -c "sed -e 's/replacethis/withthis/g' -e 's/replacethistoo/withthisaswell/g' FILE | tee FILE"
# List the files
find temp -iname "myfile.txt" | xargs -I FILE ls -l FILE
# Cat the files
find temp -iname "myfile.txt" | xargs -I FILE cat FILE
# Clean up 
rm -Rf temp
```

I run this script multiple times and have different outcomes which I don't understand.

Each time a different "myfile.txt" is modified, sometimes one of the "myfile.txt" files has 0 bytes

Why is this happening? It should be the same every time, shouldn't it? Is find only passing one, random, "myfile.txt" path to xargs each time I run this script?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? In particular, why do you pipe the `sed` output to `tee`? I'm guessing you might be looking for the `-i` option to `sed` (and then you won't need `xargs` or the `sh -c` wrapper either; `find temp -iname "myfile.txt" -exec sed -i -e 's/replacethis/withthis/g' -e 's/replacethistoo/withthisaswell/g' {} \;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is this happening? It should be the same every time shouldnt it?

This happens because of a race condition between the two parallel operations of:

- `sed` opening and reading the file
- `tee` opening and truncating the file

If `tee` wins, the file will be empty when `sed` reads it, and it will therefore be 0 bytes.

If `sed` wins, it'll read (at least parts of) the file and you'll get some data.

Since process scheduling is not predictable, you risk seeing different results each time.

Comment: if I change tee to `>` would that solve my problem or is running sed with xargs still going to have a race condition?

Comment: That will make the results more consistent. The file will *always* be truncated before `sed` runs, because the shell opens the output file before starting the command. In general, you can't use the same file for input and output. That's why `sed` has the `-i` option to perform inplace replacement.